# Speed up raster::extract with weights in r

Tags: r, vector, parallel-processing, extract, raster

I want to extract the precise mean value of raster values from an area extent defined by a polygon in r. This works using `raster::extract` with the option `weights=TRUE`. However, this operation becomes prohibitively slow with large rasters and the function doesn't seem to be parallelized, thus `beginCluster() ... endCluster()` does not speed up the process.
I need to extract the values for a range of rasters, exemplified here as r, r10 and r100. Is there a way to speed this up in r, or is there an alternative way of doing this in GDAL?

```
r <- raster(nrow=1000, ncol=1000, vals=sample(seq(0,0.8,0.01),1000000,replace=TRUE))
r10 <- aggregate(r, fact=10)
r100 <- aggregate(r, fact=100)

v = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(-100,100,80,-120), c(-70,0,70,0)))), ID = "a")
v = SpatialPolygons(list(v))

plot(r)
plot(r10)
plot(r100)
plot(v, add=T)

system.time({
precise.mean <- raster::extract(r100, v, method="simple",weights=T, normalizeWeights=T, fun=mean)    
})
user  system elapsed 
0.251   0.000   0.253 
> precise.mean
      [,1]
[1,] 0.3994278    


system.time({
  precise.mean <- raster::extract(r10, v, method="simple",weights=T, normalizeWeights=T, fun=mean)    
})

user  system elapsed 
7.447   0.000   7.446 

precise.mean
      [,1]
[1,] 0.3995429
```

[image: r1000 and the area to be extracted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I resorted the problem using `gdalUtils` working directly on the harddisk.

I used the command `gdalwarp()` to reduce the raster resolution to r10, 100.
Then `gdalwarp()` to increase the resolution of the resulting raster to the original resolution of r.
Then `gdalwarp()` with `cutline= "v.shp", crop_to_cutline =T` to mask the raster to the vector `v`.
And then `gdalinfo()` combined with `subset(x(grep("Mean=",x)))` to extract the mean values. 
All of this was packed in a `foreach() %dopar%` loop to process a number of rasters and resolution.

While complicated and probably not as precise as `extract::raster`, it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

It should actually run faster if you first call `beginCluster` (the function then deals with the parallelization). Even better would be to use version 2.7-14 which has a much faster implementation. It is currently under review at CRAN, but you can also get it here: https://github.com/rspatial/raster

Comment: Thanks. I had tried beginCluster. It detected 8 cores and made 7 available, but then only used 1 node ( confirmed by the system monitor).

Comment: It uses one node for each polygon, I suppose you only have a single polygon.

Comment: Yes, I only have a single polygon.